# getting domain\username for web app on intranet without logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web app on our intranet (VS 2005).  There are a couple pages that don't require the user to be logged into the app (feedback and the default page).  I am trying to get the domain and username to display and/or send with the feedback.  Is there a way to do this without requiring the user to log in?  I've tried `this.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]` and `this.User.Identity.Name`, but neither of them worked.

Edit:
I should have mentioned most of the users have Windows 2000 on their machines. It works on my development machine (XP), but not on the production network (where I have 2000).

Answer (score 3):

Theresa, I think this is what you're looking for...

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);

WindowsPrincipal principal = (WindowsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
WindowsIdentity identity = (WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity;

String userName= principal.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have turned Windows Authentication on in IIS for your site:

```
public string user_Name
{
    get
    {
        string x = Page.User.Identity.Name;

        x = x.Replace("YOURDOMAIN\\", "");

        return x;
    }
}
```

The x = x.Replace("DOMAIN\", ""); strips out the DOMAIN sectionof the user acccount e.g NISSAN\rmcdonough