# How to get the user's username in my intranet web application in a windows network

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML page internally which just displays a form and asks the user to fill it out. I want to automatically capture the windows domain username and machine name to submit it together with the data collected in the form.

Can I do that on the client side? HTML? JavaScript? Or am I forced to do it on the server side (which I don't know how to do... yet)

Users have XP and 7 machines and IE7,8.

BTW, I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342088/getting-domain-username-for-web-app-on-intranet-without-loggin-in) but I have to confess I don't know where in the page you would enter that "code".

Here's the code I'm using that is not working. It calls the JavaScript function, and displays `"Username="` and in the next line `"Done."`, but doesn't display the username.

And if using Chrome, it displays `<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>`.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        function get_user_Name() {
            var username = '<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>';
            document.write("Username=");
            document.write(username);
            document.write(" <br> Done.");
        }
    </script>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Training and Development Site</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="add-number-to-dnc.html">Add Phone Number to Dialer Do Not Call list</a>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="get_user_Name()">Display User Name</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also - **I'm using WebMatrix / IIS7 Express**

Comment: This is old but in case someone comes here: `<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>` is .net syntax that is evaluated on the server before the page is rendered. Obviously, this will only work if you are running in .net.

Answer (score 1):

**Using only javascript on a none IIS server then it isn't possible.**

However:

**If you are using IIS then you can use the following JS:**

```
<script language="javascript">
    var username = '<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>';

</script>
```

Assuming you have turned Windows Authentication on in IIS for your site, then C# side:

C#

```
public string user_Name
{
    get
    {
        string x = Page.User.Identity.Name;

        x = x.Replace("YOURDOMAIN\\", "");

        return x;
    }
}
```

The  `x = x.Replace("DOMAIN\\", "");` strips out the DOMAIN sectionof the user acccount e.g NISSAN\rmcdonough

Comment: Ryan, pardon my ignorance, but, where do you put that in the page, and how do you call it? Is it a JavaScript function (you can realized I'm just getting started...)

Comment: That's a C# function, sorry is this code running on an IIS site? If not you won't be able to use this or get what you want.

Comment: I'm not up to server side yet. In my question I asked if you can do this on client side only with JavaScript or something.

Comment: I was called to a meeting, I'll check that later today. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not working. See my edited question in which I added the code.

Answer (score -2):

capturing the windows domain username and machine name, I think we can't